# How can you change the date of your Mac for only one application?

Tags: macos, mac

Is it possible to change the date of your Mac so it is not system-wide, but only for certain applications? For example, changing the date to 15th June for VS Code & Firefox, but not Google Chrome, etc.

I am on an M1 MacBook Air, Monterey 12.5

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible.

## Virtual Machine

You could achieve the desired behaviour by running the applications within a [virtual machine](https://www.vmware.com/topics/glossary/content/virtual-machine.html) whose internal date has been changed. You would also need to isolate the virtual machine from the network to stop macOS fetching the time remotely.

Comment: well, you can script it - setting the date and starting the program using e.g. AppleScript.

Comment: A scripted approach will still affect all processes on the computer. What makes the task impossible, is the requirement to affect only a sub-set of processes.

Comment: A scripted approach will indeed have global effect - but only as long the script is running. It is trivial to reset the date&time using AppleScript when the program scripted is quit . But you are of course right - there is no way to set a system time for an individual app (the hint might be in “system time” )

Answer (score -2):

I created a script to solve this specific problem and then converted it into a shortcut to automate the process. Instead of manually running the script and entering a password each time, the shortcut can now launch the app automatically. The shortcut and instructions are available on a GitHub repository.
Here you go : https://github.com/ArunyaGoojar/RunAsDate-for-MacOS

Comment: Creative approach. But might be worth noting that this changes the date for **all** applications for a few seconds (which might have unexpected side effects). It also requires a user with admin rights.

Comment: I am sorry I did not read it correctly .